# Is connect-wall a myth?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, connect-wall

Note: Despite the fact that the clues appear to be cryptic ones they do not truly and completely follow the rules of cryptic clues. They do have some resemblance to them, though.

[image: Connect wall]

**A list of the clues (as they appear on the connect-wall):**

A cruel and oppresive ruler loses his ant and rules the war. (3) (G)
Small knife with a tail is called the destroyer. (5) (X)
Consent to your mom leads death. (4) (x)
Operational system and eye part lead to afterlife. (6) (h)
Perplexing singers without gravity are beautiful but deadly. (6) (f)

A confused son of Noah stuck to a woman's apparel, he is the creator of all. (6) (A)
A rainbow bridge is frozen twice. (7) (f)
Headless letter desserts don't exist but fly and kill.(7) (p)
Lack of light, with head at the bottom, strangely that also describes my habitat. (5) (0)
The first woman makes a stroll with head and feet reversed. (5) (1)

A horseman gives a coin glued to bottomless ambience. (7) (f)
Rye beer-like doesn't end. What follows is a headless noble man. He is the wisest of all beings. (6) (X)
Thomas Hardy is burning on the inside. After all, he is a leading figure of writing and knowledge. (5) (B)
A siphon, split into two, then glued together the wrong way becomes the king of heaven. (5)  (D)
Less hair is ruler of light. (6) (0)

Baby's food mixed with remains of fire is a good fortune deity. (7) (M)
Beheaded group of singers is a leader of falcons. (5) (F)
God of sun is at the end of Earth. (2) (R)
Small objects pressed together at an airplane will protect you. (6) (b)
Petrifying in more than one way, I am entertained, which is messed up. (6) (2)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The wall is as follows:

> ```
> Tyr       Shiva   Yama    Osiris  Sirens
> Brahma    Bifrost Harpies Hades   Embla
> Centaur   Kvasir  Thoth   Indra   Baldur
> Lakshmi   Horus   Ra      Wadjet  Medusa
> ```

And the groupings are

> Norse: Tyr, Bifrost, Kvasir, Embla, Baldur
> Greek: Centaur, Harpies Hades, Sirens, Medusa
> Hindu: Brahma, Lakshmi, Shiva, Yama, Indra
> Egypt: Horus, Thoth, Ra, Osiris, Wadjet

With symbols

> N: GfX10
> G: fp0f2
> H: AMXxD
> E: FBRhb

Ordering the symbols by the answers alphabetically, and treating those as imgur urls, per Gareth's answer, we get four letter grids.

> Combining these grids, we get a bigger grid!
>
> ```
> KSEIRYKLAVIR
> DUGDOMUNHKIY
> RHKIMQUEZGKE
> OSUREBRECEAR
> HESTIAURABRF
> TBESLSNRTRTR
> ASKGATHEIAIE
> HKEARESNLGKY
> PARVATIUAIEJ
> ADOHYDVMKAYA
> TISXOXUANNAN
> ```
>
> With more mythology than you can shake a stick at:
> Thor, Parvati, Vishnu, Modgud, Freyr, Freyja, Geb, Bragi, Hestia, Skadi, Amun, Valkyries, Bastet, Ask, Zeus, Set, Cerberus, Theia, Anubis, Hera, Styx, Aegir, Buri, Aura, Magi?, Odin, Hathor, Ares

Note from OP:

> I am accepting this answer because Sconibulus practically solved the puzzle and obviously it could become boring and tedious to find all the mythical things I have included (despite them being only from the 4 mythology groups). The full list is as follows: AEGIR, ALGEA, AMUN, ANUBIS, ARES, ASK, AURA, AUXO, BASTET, BES, BRAGI, BURI, CERBERUS, EIR, EROS, FREYJA, FREYR, GEB, HATHOR, HERA, HESTIA, HOD, KALI, KARTIKEYA, KHNUM, KRISHNA, KUK, MODGUD, NANNA, OD, ODIN, PARVATI, QETESH, RHEA, RIG, SEKER, SET, SHU, SKADI, STYX, THEIA, THOR, VALKYRIES, VE, VISHNU, ZEUS

Comment: Ha. I (independently) had the exact set, including the same wrong answer and the same doubt about it :-).

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan - how do you even get there? From the clue?

Comment: All the words and groupings are correct now :)

Comment: @Sconibulus I have the next step. If you do too, I'll keep off your toes; otherwise I'll post it. Let me know.

Comment: @MariaDeleva You don't get there from the clue. You fail to make sense of the clue and go looking for Egyptian protective deities.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I do not, I've tried a couple imgur things, but nothing that's worked, go ahead.

Comment: Incidentally, I see you have a question mark on one of them: it's HOT inside TH.

Comment: Aha, nice. (But is there *another* step? I'm guessing not but wouldn't bet much against.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan my best guess for next step would be with unused letters, which I have starting with 'KIUKIHKIMQ' at this point, so either I'm still missing a bunch, or it's less obvious than I first thought

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan- there is no next step - just more "than you can shake a stick at" - Sconibulus, you have no idea how right you are. :)

Answer (score 5):

**Next step**

The solutions of the wall lead to

> one alphanumeric character per solution.

Putting these

> into alphabetical order within each mythology, and then using them as imgur filenames,

we find

> the following grids of letters:
>  Hindu:
>      `A S K G A T`
>      `H K E A R E`
>      `P A R V A T`
>      `A D O H Y D`
>      `T I S X O X`
>
>  Norse:
>      `K L A V I R`
>      `U N H K I Y`
>      `U E Z G K E`
>      `R E C E A R`
>      `U R A B R F`
>      `N R T R T R`
>
>  Greek:
>      `K S E I R Y`
>      `D U G D O M`
>      `R H K I M Q`
>      `O S U R E B`
>      `H E S T I A`
>      `T B E S L S`
>
>  Egyptian:
>      `H E I A I E`
>      `S N L G K Y`
>      `I U A I E J`
>      `V M K A Y A`
>      `U A N N A N`

within which we find

> Thor (Norse), Freyr (Norse), Skadi (Norse) and Kali (Hindu). (Also Hestia (Latin) and Parvat (name, I think, of a king and city both named for Parvati), but I don't think those are needed here.)

Perhaps

> we're now meant to pick Kali, as odd one out? Or, more likely, there's some further step making more use of the grids. (I wondered whether perhaps there would be one horizontal and one vertical name in each grid, with the intersection letters being needed, but it doesn't look like it.)

Comment: Great! You found the grids. The approach is a bit different, though. :)